# npm fetch just package.json of package and dump to stdout

Tags: node.js, npm

I frequently find myself wanting to inspect the dependencies of a package without actually downloading the whole thing. Is there any easy way to download just the package.json of a package and send it to stdout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `npm info`. For example:

```
npm info cheerio
```

Part of the output:

```
dependencies:
   { 'css-select': '~1.0.0',
     entities: '~1.1.1',
     htmlparser2: '~3.8.1',
     'dom-serializer': '~0.1.0',
     lodash: '^3.2.0' },
devDependencies:
   { benchmark: '~1.0.0',
     coveralls: '~2.10',
     'expect.js': '~0.3.1',
     istanbul: '~0.2',
     jsdom: '~0.8.9',
     jshint: '~2.5.1',
     mocha: '*',
     xyz: '~0.5.0' },
```